# Error while compiling Qt embedded for Beagleboard (ARM)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile Qt embedded for ARM. I have followed the instructions both [here](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/09/10/cross-compiling-qtx11/) and [here](http://webkit.sed.hu/blog/20100427/qtwebkit-cross-compilation-gcc-arm-linux). I am using latest Angstrom toolchain and qt-embedded-linux-opensource-src-4.5.3 and I am using Ubuntu 10.10 x86.

Here steps I past:

- Configured qws/linux-arm-g++/qmake.conf file for my toolchain. Here it's content:

  ```
  #
  # qmake configuration for building with arm-linux-g++
  #

  include(../../common/g++.conf)
  include(../../common/linux.conf)
  include(../../common/qws.conf)

  # modifications to g++.conf
  QMAKE_CC                = arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc
  QMAKE_CXX               = arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++
  QMAKE_LINK              = arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++
  QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++

  # modifications to linux.conf
  QMAKE_AR                = arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ar cqs
  QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
  QMAKE_STRIP             = arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-strip

  load(qt_config)
  ```
- Set my toolchain path:

  ```
  export PATH=/home/olcay/angstrom/arm/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Configured qt with:

  ```
  ./configure -arch arm -little-endian -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++
  ```
- Run make.

While running make I am getting this error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/olcay/qt-embedded/src/corelib'
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_SHARED -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT3_SUPPORT -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DHB_EXPORT=Q_CORE_EXPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -I../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I../../include -I../../include/QtCore -I.rcc/release-shared-emb-arm -Iglobal -I../3rdparty/zlib -I../3rdparty/harfbuzz/src -I.moc/release-shared-emb-arm -o .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qatomic_arm.o arch/arm/qatomic_arm.cpp
/home/olcay/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++: 1: ELF: not found
/home/olcay/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make[1]: *** [.obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qatomic_arm.o] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/olcay/qt-embedded/src/corelib'
make: *** [sub-corelib-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

I have also noticed that while config there is a warning and same error line in make:

```
    The system floating point format could not be detected.
    This may cause data to be generated in a wrong format
    Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to see the final report.
    /home/olcay/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++: 1: ELF: not found
    /home/olcay/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

And changing configure line as @Luca Carlon described does not solve the problem.

Please help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed that I have downloaded my Angstrom tool-chain for 64 bit host platform but I am using 32 bit host. After downloading correct tool-chain I have managed to compile Qt. And I found that an "ELF not found" error occurs when you try to run an application which is not build for your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Replace -arch arm with -embedded arm and try again if you want to build Qt Embedded.